Why does g++13 require lib-path relative VSCode working path while g++-14 requires path relative compiled source file?
I build C++ programs on macOS 12.7 using VSCode and tasks.json.
I spent hours trying to configure VSCode tasks.json to build with both g++-14 and g++-13. And I am still confused why I had to change the path to the lua-library to link from being relative to the source code compiled to a path relative the VSCode startup directory.
This g++-13 invokation compiles ok:
/usr/local/Cellar/gcc@13/13.3.0/bin/g++-13 -fdiagnostics-color=always -std=c++23 -fsanitize=address,undefined -g -Wl,-v lib/macos/lua-5.2.4_MacOS1011_lib/liblua52.a /Users/kjell-olovhogdal/Documents/Github/cratchit/src/main.cpp -o /Users/kjell-olovhogdal/Documents/Github/cratchit/cratchit.out

This g++14 invokation compiles ok:
/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/14.1.0_1/bin/g++-14 --sysroot=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -fdiagnostics-color=always -std=c++23 -g -Wl,-v -fsanitize=address,undefined -fno-omit-frame-pointer ../lib/macos/lua-5.2.4_MacOS1011_lib/liblua52.a /Users/kjell-olovhogdal/Documents/Github/cratchit/src/main.cpp -o /Users/kjell-olovhogdal/Documents/Github/cratchit/cratchit.out

Note that g++-13 invokation lists 'lib/macos/lua-5.2.4_MacOS1011_lib/liblua52.a' while g++-14 invokation lists '../lib/macos/lua-5.2.4_MacOS1011_lib/liblua52.a'.
After I installed g++-13 (macOS 12.7 and Brew) I failed to make my code compile with it. It complained it failed to find liblua52.a although I called g++-13 in the same way as I had called g++14. After having played around with different ways to instruct g++-13 to link with liblua52.a I found out that the fix was to change the path to the library to be relative the working directory of VSCode. But g++-14 compiled and linked just fine with a librray path relative the source code file compiled.
Can anyone explain to me what may cause this behaviour for building from VSCode? Explicitly, what actually determines how the g++ compiler interprets a relative path for files listed in the argument list?
Many thanks in advance!
/Kjell-Olov

I found the problem. The options::cwd setting in VSCode task.json configuration differed sigh!
        "options": {
          "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
        },

vs:
        "options": {
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
        },

NOTE: I removed the "options" with the "cwd" setting and now relies on that I always starts VSCode from the workspace directory (and just ensures the path to my lua-lib is relative this path).
The original problem happened because I used ChatGPT to help me with all the 'magic' settings for VSCode configurations I really never had time nor the inclination to be bothered with :-/.
Hm...maybe time to go back to a plain text editor and hard coded build scripts :o!
